# How to develop Complex element

Tags: svg, react-native, react-native-ios

Good day.
How to develop the next element?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwtOT.png)

```
[I managed to do with HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/msn18pgL/)
```

Converted to react-native with react-native-svg

```
    <View style={{width: 200}}>
        <Svg width="200" height="160" viewBox="0 0 196.7 160" >
            <G>
                <Defs>
                    <Path
                        id="SVGID_1_"
                        d="M179.3,29H13.8c0,0-7.7-0.1-10.5-2.9C1.2,23.9,0,21.3,0,21.3v121.3c0,9.6,7.8,17.3,17.3,17.3h162c9.6,0,17.3-7.8,17.3-17.3V46.3C196.7,36.8,188.9,29,179.3,29z" />
                </Defs>
                <ClipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                    <Use href="#SVGID_1_" style={{overflow: "visible"}} />
                </ClipPath>
                <G clipPath="url(#SVGID_2_)">
                    <Image
                        style={{overflow: "visible"}}
                        width="200"
                        height="160"
                        href={this.props.image}
                        transform="matrix(0.1354 0 0 0.1354 -10.4909 17.5768)" />
                </G>
            </G>
        </Svg>
    </View>;
```

transform="matrix(0.1354 0 0 0.1354 -10.4909 17.5768)" - It is not right!

I found [react-native transform props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms.html)
But I do not know how to write correctly on the react-native

Comment: *sigh* Alright, so welcome to Stackoverflow. While you are free to do questions, nobody is going to answer you unless you give the description of what you tried and what is the issue. Also, you are asking a question that can easily be answered by searching the Internet or this very same site.

Comment: [I managed to do with HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/2g4pvhnd/)

Comment: <Svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="6 0 200 160" >
    <G>
        <Defs>
             <ClipPath id="clip-path">
                 <Path d="M179.33,9.5H13.83S6.1,9.38,3.33,6.58A19,19,0,0,1,0,1.83V123.17A17.33,17.33,0,0,0,17.33,140.5h162a17.33,17.33,0,0,0,17.33-17.33V26.83A17.33,17.33,0,0,0,179.33,9.5Z"
                 fill="none" />
             </ClipPath>
        </Defs>
        <G clipPath="url(#clip-path)">
            <Image width="240" height="150" href={this.props.image}/>
        </G>
    </G>
</Svg>

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are mixing an Image inside an Svg tag which I don't think that module supports. You are supposed to do the image with the Svg tags. Remove the Image tag and it should work.

Comment: No. Image component from [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/)